# Packages needed to get sound working

Tags: ubuntu, audio

I just installed Ubuntu Server 12.10. I am using openbox and startx for my gui session. I decided not to post in the Ubuntu forum because I felt this issue might be relevant to other distros as well, especially Debian based ones.

I installed `firefox` and `flashplugin-installer` so I could watch youtube videos. The videos seem like the work fine, however, I seem to be without sound.

I also got `volumeicon-alsa` and `alsa-utils` but when I run `alsamixer` I get:

```
cannot open mixer: No such file or directory
```

when I try to run `volumeicon` I get

```
volumeicon: alsa_backend.c:86: asound_get_volume: Assertion `m_elem != ((void *))' failed.
```

I don't mind using something other than alsa if I need to. I would just like to know what packages I need to install to be able to get sound on youtube videos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get the available sound card device list by:

```
aplay -l
```

Then you can create either `~/.asoundrc` or `/etc/asound.conf` ( go with the second one, then it will be set for every user on the machine ) with the default device settings. So write into one of this files accordingly to the output of the first command. For example my output was:

card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
- Subdevices: 1/1
- Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
**card 1**: SB [HDA ATI SB], **device 0**: CONEXANT Analog [CONEXANT Analog]
- Subdevices: 1/1
- Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

See the lines I made bold? That is the line for my soundcard, so I use that data to enter into my `/etc/asound.conf`:

```
defaults.pcm.card 1
defaults.pcm.device 0
defaults.ctl.card 1
```

Do this for yourself (use all three configuration option), and dont forget to login/logout.

Comment: Thanks but `aplay -l` resulted in `aplay: device_list:252: no soundcards found...`

Comment: Maybe you don't have the permission on your user to do this, we can test this, go into "root-mode":  
 `sudo -i`, login, and try `aplay -l` again.

Comment: Thanks! I also had to run `adduser <me> audio`, but now it works just fine.

Comment: Ye, that was my next advice going to be [:. Glad for helping!